# Angular Webpack Modular Federation with Token Injection

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation

I am creating micro frontends project. I am facing an issue in token injection.

I've a library project which is consumed by mfe1 and then loaded in the shell app.

**Library Module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    EclatechCoreComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  exports: [
    EclatechCoreComponent
  ]
})
export class EclatechCoreModule {
  
  public static forRoot(config: Environment): ModuleWithProviders<EclatechCoreModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: EclatechCoreModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ENVIRONMENT,
          useValue: config
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**From mfe1,**

in the module imports

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SetupComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: SetupComponent,
      }
    ]),

    EclatechCoreModule.forRoot(config)
  ],
  
  exports:[
    SetupComponent
  ]
})
export class SetupModule { }
```

Now, When I load the `mfe1` the config are loaded correctly and everything works but when I load the `mfe1` through the `shell` app it returns with error.

**Shell app error**

```
core.js:6479 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(SetupModule)[BusinessService -> BusinessService -> ConfigService -> ConfigService -> InjectionToken ENVIRONMENT -> InjectionToken ENVIRONMENT -> InjectionToken ENVIRONMENT]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken ENVIRONMENT!
```

**Environment**

```
export interface Environment {
    gatewayUrl: string;
    orgServiceUrl: string;
    client_id: string;
}
```

**ENVIRONMENT**

```
import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";
import { Environment } from "./environment.interface";


export const ENVIRONMENT : InjectionToken<Environment> = new InjectionToken<Environment>('ENVIRONMENT');
```

Comment: Hi , did u find any solution to this problem ? I am facing the same issue

Comment: same issue here. Trying to pass base API URL to shared services.

Comment: No solution yet!

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

try to set injectiontoken default value in **ENVIRONMENT** file.

set it with **config** from your providers

```
providers: [
{
          provide: ENVIRONMENT,
          useValue: config
        }
]
```

And it will work.

there is an injection example:
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/10/11/angular-dependency-injection

> const export BREAD_TOKEN = new InjectionToken('bread', {
> providedIn: 'root',   factory: () => '' });

code example for **ENVIRONMENT**:

```
import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";
import { Environment } from "./environment.interface";
import { config } from "";

let defaultEnv : Environment = {
  gatewayUrl: config.gatewayUrl;
  orgServiceUrl: config.orgServiceUrl;
  client_id: config.client_id;
};
export const ENVIRONMENT : InjectionToken<Environment> = new InjectionToken<Environment>('ENVIRONMENT'{
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => defaultEnv
});
```